# Why Self-defined Matlab Function Return Empty Matrix

Tags: matlab

The function is supposed to return a value. However, when I type:

```
    val(1d4)
```

it returns

```
    ans =

    []
```

However, if I copied line by line, and set all parameters (V eps_today etc.), and run in the command window, it works fine...Have no clue where the problem is. Thanks:)

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %This function calculates the value function of both small and big%
    %investment                                                       %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    function negval=val(k_next)

    global V eps_today k_today eps_gv k_gv z_today delta xi

    theta=0.5327; beta=0.95; rho=0.7675; sigma_eta=0.7704;

    %identify the grid point that falls just below
    klo=max(sum(k_next>k_gv),1);
    %above
    khi=klo+1;

    %Linear Interpolation, effectively only on the dimension of k
    if klo<size(k_gv,2)
        V_temp=V(:,klo)+(k_next-k_gv(klo))/(k_gv(khi)-k_gv(klo))*(V(:,khi)-V(:,klo));
    else
       %when k_next> maximum point of k_gv 
        V_temp=V(:,size(k_gv,2));
    end

    EV=mean(V_temp,1);

    negval=-(exp(z_today+eps_today)*k_today^theta-xi*k_today-(k_next-(1-delta)*k_today)+beta*EV);
    end
```

Comment: Sounds like your global variables have not been set their values. The easiest is to use the debugger. Set a break point anywhere after the `global` line and run the code again. When it stops check that the variables have values. You can then proceed until the end of the function to check that everything works as expected (it probably does, the code looks OK). I bet that the global variables are undefined within the function.

Comment: Btw. globals are evil, "never" use them and you will save a lot of headache.

Comment: Agree with @PetrH, if you want to get (a lot of) variables, consider using a struct. Your function call could look something like: `negval=val(environment,k_next)` where the fields of the `struct` environment would be your variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to replicate your problem but I couldn't. If I do not set the global variables Matlab shouts and refuses to proceed through the function. Setting some of them to empty values was the same (did not try them all).  If I do set the globals then the function always gives me a value.

But I strongly suspect it has something to do with the globals anyway (can you show the code where they are initialized?). As I mentioned in the comment I would get rid of them, the code could look like this

Main programme

```
%set parameters
Pars.beta = beta=0.95;
Pars.theta = 0.5327;
Pars.rho=0.7675; 
Pars.sigma_eta=0.7704;
Pars.delta = ...;
Pars.xi = ...;

%set grid
eps_gv = ...
k_gv = ...
ne = length(eps_gv);
nk = length(k_gv);

V = zeros(ne,nk);
k_next = ...;

value = val(k_next,V,eps_gv,k_gv,Pars);
```

Val function

```
negval = function val(k_next,V,eps_gv,k_gv,Pars)

theta=Pars.theta; beta=Pars.beta; rho=Pars.rho; etc.
```

You don't even need `eps_today` and `k_today` as these should be the values on the grid (ie `eps_gv` and `k_gv`). I don't know what `z_today` is but there should either be a grid for `z` or `z_today` should be a parameter, in which case it should be in `Pars`. Of course if you use `eps_gv` and `k_gv` instead of `eps_today` and `k_today` the `negval = ...` line needs to be modified to take account of them being arrays not scalars.

One last comment, there is a bug on the `EV=mean(V_temp,1);` line. The `mean` function calculates the average of (the columns of) `V`. To calculate the expected value you need to do a weighted average where you weight each row of `V` by the probability of `eps` being `eps_gv(1)` (ie `sum(V(i,:)*prob_eps(i))`, sum going over `i`) . What you did works only if all shocks have equal probability. Pointing out since I am not sure you are aware of that.

Comment: Many thanks, PetrH. I didn't show the main part of the function, which is why initialization of most global variables are not there. In my situation, using global variables seem a bit of inevitable, since there is an optimization of the above function in the main function. For the expected value comment, you're right and I do have some probability vector in my original code. I intended to highlight the problem without giving extras. I'll try the debugger and see what it says. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3920624 Of course if you decide to get rid off the globals you will have to modify the other functions as well but you can definitely do it and it is well worth it. Anyway if you decide to stick with them and if I am right that the globals are at fault then it should work as long as you make sure they are always set before you call the function. I guess the problem occurred when you tested the function by calling it from the command line since the globals were not in your workspace. If you run the main script it will probably work as it did for me.